# Solve the differential equation $(4+t^2) \frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty = 4t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $$(4+t^2) \frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty = 4t$$

Solution:

$$(4+t^2) \frac{dy}{dt} + 2ty = \frac{d}{dt}[(4+t^2)y]$$

How?

Here's what I did:

$$\frac{d}{dt}[(4+t^2)y] = 4t$$

Then we integrate both side:

$$(4+t^2)y = 2t^2 + c$$

$$y = \frac{2t^2+c}{4+t^2}$$

I don't get the first step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use $(fg)'=f'g+g'f$. In this case $f=y(t)$ and $g=4+t^2$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the trick, solve the homogeneous equation

$$(t^2+4)y'+2ty=0,$$ which is separable.

$$\frac{y'}y+\frac{2t}{t^2+4}=0$$

is solved by integration,

$$\log y+\log(t^2+4)=\log(y(t^2+4))=c,$$ and $$y(t^2+4)=c.$$

Now, by variation of the constant,

$$y(t^2+4)=c(t),$$
$$y'(t^2+4)+2ty=c'(t)=4t,$$
 and finally

$$y=\frac{2t^2+c}{t^2+4}.$$